# Combine results of two different queries into a single query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a MySQL table containing login logs. Each entry contains user email, IP address, timestamp and the login result (0 fail, 1 success).

```
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| ip         | email            | datetime   | result |
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498362 | 0      |
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498363 | 1      |
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498364 | 0      |
| 1134706444 | user2@domain.com | 1426498365 | 0      |
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
```

My goal is to create a unique query to extract the count of failed logins from a given timestamp, and the timestamp of the last login for `user1@domain.com`. In this case I would like to obtain (suppose for simplicity that all entries are after the required timestamp)

```
+--------+------------+
| count  | datetime   |
+--------+------------+
| 3      | 1426498364 |
+--------+------------+
```

Until now, I've created two separated queries to extract results separately

```
SELECT COUNT(result) as count FROM (SELECT result FROM accesslogs WHERE datetime>1426498360 AND result=0) as subt
SELECT MAX(datetime) as datetime FROM accesslogs WHERE email=`user1@domain.com`
```

Now I'm tring to combine them to get results with a single query. I was wondering about using `JOIN` statement, but I don't know a column where queries may join. What can I do?

Comment: As per my concern :  SELECT COUNT(result) AS COUNT, MAX(logDate) FROM accesslogs 
GROUP BY email WHERE result = 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this, something as

```
select 
sum( 
  case 
   when result=0 and datetime>1426498360 
   then  1 else 0 end 
) as `count`,
max(
   case 
   when email = 'user1@domain.com' then datetime end
) as datetime 
from accesslogs ;
```

Here is an example

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| ip         | email            | datetime   | result |
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498362 |      0 |
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498363 |      1 |
| 2130706433 | user1@domain.com | 1426498364 |      0 |
| 1134706444 | user2@domain.com | 1426498365 |      0 |
+------------+------------------+------------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select 
    -> sum( 
    ->   case 
    ->    when result=0 and datetime>1426498360 
    ->    then  1 else 0 end 
    -> ) as `count`,
    -> max(
    ->    case 
    ->    when email = 'user1@domain.com' then datetime end
    -> ) as datetime 
    -> from test ;
+-------+------------+
| count | datetime   |
+-------+------------+
|     3 | 1426498364 |
+-------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from (selete statement a) a join (selete statement b) b
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu I think I know what he want, my sql output is the same with the question owner's best chioce.And also the owner said he was **wondering about using JOIN**.In that case he doesnt need to put any column that join on.My answer is only useless when people dont understand that statment a and b is their two column select statment

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNION ALL` but both queries must have same columns.
I would suggest add `text column` to each query descibing type of value in other column like:

`SELECT COUNT(result) as count, 'count' AS TYPE FROM (SELECT result FROM accesslogs WHERE datetime>1426498360 AND result=0) as subt`

`UNION ALL`

`SELECT MAX(datetime) as datetime, 'max' AS TYPE FROM accesslogs WHERE email='user1@domain.com'`

EDIT: Sorry but I realised that this is more what you are trying to do (this is t-sql code but should work)

```
    SELECT a.email, a.count, b.datetime FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(result) as count, email FROM (SELECT result, email FROM 
    accesslogs AND result=0) as subt
    GROUP BY email) a
    JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(datetime) as datetime , email FROM accesslogs  GROUP BY email) b  
    on a.email = b.email
    WHERE a.email='user1@domain.com'
    AND a.datetime >'2012-12-17'
```

Comment: The query results in 2 rows (one for max timestamp, one for count), I need 2 separate columns. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQLs `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. See if this works for you:

Any email:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(resultSet) as loginAttempts, 
COUNT(resultSet) - SUM(resultSet) as failedAttempts
FROM accesslogs 
GROUP BY email;
```

Specific email:

```
SELECT COUNT(result) as count, MAX(logDate) FROM accesslogs 
GROUP BY email
HAVING email='user1@example.com';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It returns only results related to `user1@example.com`, while I need to count failed attempts for all users.

Comment: I edited my code and added the "Any email" section, see if this works.

Comment: Oh, wait, I didn't take into account that you need to count failed attempts.